# Determine version of mosquitto

Tags: mosquitto

I'm looking for a way to determine mosquitto's version BEFORE starting it.
Of course I could start it and subscribe to `$SYS/broker/version`.

For security reasons mosquitto needs an extended configuration file since version 2.0, which I have to generate depending on the found mosquitto version.

Since I'm starting a mosquitto process programmatically, I don't want to start a process, get the version, quit the process, and restart it with a different config file.

Unfortunately, the mosquitto.exe doesn't contain any version information, so  `GetFileVersionInfo` does not work.

Is there any other reliable information to find out if it's a version less oder greater than 2.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's wrong with `mosquitto -h` it outputs the version information in the first line and then exit on it's own:

```
$ mosquitto -h
mosquitto version 2.0.12

mosquitto is an MQTT v5.0/v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.

Usage: mosquitto [-c config_file] [-d] [-h] [-p port]

 -c : specify the broker config file.
 -d : put the broker into the background after starting.
 -h : display this help.
 -p : start the broker listening on the specified port.
      Not recommended in conjunction with the -c option.
 -v : verbose mode - enable all logging types. This overrides
      any logging options given in the config file.

See https://mosquitto.org/ for more information.
```

Also you could just generate a valid 2.0 config file every time as this will still work with earlier versions of Mosquitto.

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you very much, I didn't come up with this brilliant idea. I was thinking all the time if I have to create a database with the version numbers and the corresponding file sizes or some other elaborate solution.